# Can I add a multipageeditor to a multipageeditor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an EMF project and i want to use the editor from the emf inside a multipageeditor i have created.

Can I do it? or should I change the multipageeditor from the emf to regular editorpart (keep just one editor)

Comment: Maybe it's easier to just add the EMF editor's pages to your own editor.

Comment: I have not much details on the "tweaks": mainly that you need one ActionBarContributor who know about all the sub-MultiPageEditorPart, instead of having one ActionBarContributor for each MultiPageEditorPart.

Answer (score 0):

Considering [`MultiPageEditor`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/part/MultiPageEditor.java.htm) is deprecated, I assume you are referring to [`MultiPageEditorPart`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/part/MultiPageEditorPart.java.htm).

In that case, yes, you should be able to add a MultiPageEditorPart within a MultiPageEditorPart, as mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg57033.html), with some limits/tweaks to do for

- the individual action bar contributors (build your own `ActionBarContributor` based off of `MultiPageActionBarContributor`)
- the Properties View

Comment: 1. I am referring to MultiPageEditorPart.
2. i'm not sure i understood the tweak you are suggesting.
 i have one multiPageEditorPart- "A" with an implemented ActionBarContributor B, and i want to create a container editor C {a multiPageEditorPart itself) that will hold editor A in it.
Do you suggest i override the createSite method in editor C and create a specialized site that holds the contributor B?

thanks for the quick reply.